# How to make a perfect cross fading animation?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make 4 cross fading images above each other. I have this but it's got a little problem.

```
 <div>
   <img class="first-img" src="img1.jpg">
    <img class="second-img" src="img2.jpg">
    <img class="third-img" src="img3.jpg">
    <img class="fourth-img" src="img4.jpg">
 </div>
```

css:

```
 img {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 animation: crossfade 20s infinite;
 }

 .first-img {
 z-index: 4;
 }

 .second-img {
 z-index: 3;
 animation-delay: 5s;
 }

 .third-img {
 z-index: 2;
 animation-delay: 10s;
 }

 .fourth-img {
 z-index: 1;
 animation-delay: 15s;
 }

 @keyframes crossfade {
 0% {opacity: 1;}
 15% {opacity: 1;}
 25% {opacity: 0;}
 90% {opacity: 0;}
 100% {opacity: 1;}
 }
```

Problem starts after the last image (the fourth), The fourth image fades into the background and then the first image starts looping again.
I want to get rid of this weird cut between the end of loop, where the last image fades into the background for a small while, What would be the perfect animation values to make the fourth image crossfades directly with the first image at the loop's end?

Comment: Works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/fUEnk/

Comment: An example with images also works fine http://jsfiddle.net/M8tbD/5/

Comment: Ruirize and Danko, the OP is right. The last image starts fading to the background color, before the 1st image starts fading in.. see http://codepen.io/gpetrioli/pen/hyrjl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you notice, it is not only the last image.. it is all of them after the first cycle.

This happens because your images all start with `opacity:1` (*the default value*). But after they have started animating the `keyframes` takes control of the `opacity` so now they are all 0 except the two that are cross-fading each time.

While they are cross-fading, one from 0-1 and the other from 1-0 they are at various stages of semi-transparency, so the background will bleed in as well.. The only way to avoid it, is to fade the new image over the existing and after it is completely shown set the previous one to 0 opacity.

Try

```
@keyframes crossfade {
    0% {opacity: 1; z-index:10}
   15% {opacity: 1;}
   25% {opacity: 0;}
   80% {opacity: 0; z-index:1}
   90% {opacity: 1;}
  100% {opacity: 1; z-index:1}
}
```

Demo at http://codepen.io/gpetrioli/pen/hyrjl

Comment: Yes, thank you a lot! That explained what's going on and fixed it as well, thx.